# Worksheet_Calculate event not working

Tags: excel, vba

why Worksheet_Calculate event is not activating when i calculate the sheet by Shift+F9?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Columns("A:F").AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code inside a worksheet code page or a macro? Have you saved the workbook, or is this still hanging out in an unsaved book? Did you set a breakpoint (F9) on the one line of code to see if it's executing and just not operating as expected?

Answer (score 0):

1. insure the file is **.xlsm** and not **.xlsx**
2. insure macros are enabled
3. insure Events are enabled
4. insure the sub is in the worksheet code area
5. enter something like `=NOW()` in any cell
6. try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>